# What setting to use for jenkins tunnel?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to run a jenkins system on my macbook for testing

Jenkins is running in the mac "Docker Desktop" in Kubernetes, using a helm chart

It has a Kubernetes slave set up with the Kubernetes plugin

When I start a job, a new Kubernetes pod is started.  But it is unable to fully attach to Jenkins and so run the job

Here's some logs from the docker container running the Jenkins master

As you can see, it seems to work fine until the "tunnel" is used

Any ideas what to set the tunnel to?  I've tried leaving it blank, setting to the IP of the Jenkins Kubernetes instance or setting it to localhost.  None of these work

Is this perhaps a networking problem with Kubernetes or Docker?

```
docker logs -f f8ad22879548
INFO: Container is waiting kubernetes-slave-nvfvb [jnlp]: ContainerStateWaiting(message=null, reason=ContainerCreating, additionalProperties={})
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:00 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
INFO: Waiting for Pod to be scheduled (1/200): kubernetes-slave-nvfvb
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:01 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
INFO: Container is waiting kubernetes-slave-nvfvb [jnlp]: ContainerStateWaiting(message=null, reason=ContainerCreating, additionalProperties={})
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:01 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
INFO: Waiting for Pod to be scheduled (2/200): kubernetes-slave-nvfvb
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:02 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
INFO: Container is waiting kubernetes-slave-nvfvb [jnlp]: ContainerStateWaiting(message=null, reason=ContainerCreating, additionalProperties={})
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:02 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
INFO: Waiting for Pod to be scheduled (3/200): kubernetes-slave-nvfvb
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:03 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
INFO: Waiting for agent to connect (0/100): kubernetes-slave-nvfvb
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:04 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
INFO: Waiting for agent to connect (1/100): kubernetes-slave-nvfvb
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:05 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
...etc etc..
INFO: Waiting for agent to connect (99/100): kubernetes-slave-nvfvb
Feb 06, 2019 3:51:46 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher logLastLines
SEVERE: Error in provisioning; agent=KubernetesSlave name: kubernetes-slave-nvfvb, template=PodTemplate{inheritFrom='', name='kubernetes-slave', namespace='', instanceCap=2, idleMinutes=2, label='utils', nodeSelector='utils', nodeUsageMode=NORMAL, workspaceVolume=EmptyDirWorkspaceVolume [memory=false], volumes=[HostPathVolume [mountPath=/var/run/docker.sock, hostPath=/var/run/docker.sock]], containers=[ContainerTemplate{name='jnlp', image='adriagalin/jenkins-jnlp-slave:1.4', workingDir='/home/jenkins', command='', args='${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}', resourceRequestCpu='200m', resourceRequestMemory='256Mi', resourceLimitCpu='200m', resourceLimitMemory='256Mi', livenessProbe=org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.ContainerLivenessProbe@56ff8e15}], yaml=}. Container jnlp. Logs: INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://10.74.121.25:8080/]
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:08 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:08 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: 10.74.121.25
  Agent port:    50000
  Identity:      cd:a5:60:45:4d:45:7c:53:83:48:5b:d3:d5:02:68:4f
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:08 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Feb 06, 2019 3:50:08 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to 10.74.121.25:50000
Feb 06, 2019 3:51:34 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to 10.74.121.25:50000 (retrying:2)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to 10.74.121.25:50000
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:243)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:500)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:364)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:287)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:204)
        ... 3 more


Feb 06, 2019 3:51:46 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
WARNING: Error in provisioning; agent=KubernetesSlave name: kubernetes-slave-nvfvb, template=PodTemplate{inheritFrom='', name='kubernetes-slave', namespace='', instanceCap=2, idleMinutes=2, label='utils', nodeSelector='utils', nodeUsageMode=NORMAL, workspaceVolume=EmptyDirWorkspaceVolume [memory=false], volumes=[HostPathVolume [mountPath=/var/run/docker.sock, hostPath=/var/run/docker.sock]], containers=[ContainerTemplate{name='jnlp', image='adriagalin/jenkins-jnlp-slave:1.4', workingDir='/home/jenkins', command='', args='${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}', resourceRequestCpu='200m', resourceRequestMemory='256Mi', resourceLimitCpu='200m', resourceLimitMemory='256Mi', livenessProbe=org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.ContainerLivenessProbe@56ff8e15}], yaml=}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Agent is not connected after 100 seconds, status: Running
        at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher.launch(KubernetesLauncher.java:224)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:294)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Feb 06, 2019 3:51:46 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesSlave _terminate
INFO: Terminating Kubernetes instance for agent kubernetes-slave-nvfvb
Feb 06, 2019 3:51:46 PM org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesSlave deleteSlavePod
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker inspect the container running jenkins

```
docker inspect  eaddfb02c83c|grep _50000
```

this gives some variables which are set with the correct address

```
$ docker inspect  eaddfb02c83c|grep _50000
            "MY_RELEASE_JENKINS_AGENT_PORT_50000_TCP_PORT=50000",
            "MY_RELEASE_JENKINS_AGENT_PORT_50000_TCP_ADDR=10.102.9.168",
            "MY_RELEASE_JENKINS_AGENT_PORT_50000_TCP_PROTO=tcp",
            "MY_RELEASE_JENKINS_AGENT_PORT_50000_TCP=tcp://10.102.9.168:50000",
```

use this information to set the "Jenkins tunnel" argument in the Cloud Kubernetes, using the values above for example the setting is 10.102.9.168:50000